# Will we need to replay all levels in Mario Kart 7 for 3 stars, gold wheel, VR rating on the new 3DS XL?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, mario-kart-7

When the 3DS XL comes out, will we lose all the 3 stars rating, gold wheel, and VR score if we play MK 7 on the new console?

I heard in the past that the SD card won't be able to save those data, because it was worried that game players can just duplicate many SD cards that way.  But is there some other way, for example, if 3DS can transfer data through WiFi (the StreetPass mechanism), then maybe there can be a way to either copy or move the game achievements to one and only one 3DS console?  (or if each game player can log in, and retrieve those achievements on their console... and players usually won't share login with each other).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On page 3 of the Other Settings section of System Settings, you'll find an option called System Transfer. This lets you move all your stuff from one 3DS to another, including save data. [This page](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/3ds/en_na/data_transfer.jsp) has a bit more info. Note that you can only do this a limited number of times and all the data will be erased from the original 3DS.

Comment: interesting... so we can't have those achievements on both our 3DS and 3DS XL...  but I suppose some people may just keep the 3DS XL and sell the 3DS

Comment: By the way, I got a 3DS XL, and plug the game cartridge of MK 7 in, and surprisingly, all my past racing records, including my Mii, are all right there on the new 3DS XL.  So looks like somehow the data is also saved on the cartridge to transfer over as well, which is nice